# Modules over a product of Algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Suppose $A = A_1 \times A_2$ where $A_1$ and $A_2$ are associative algebras (Not necessarily unitary).  Show that any $A$-Module $T$ is isomorphic to $M \oplus N$ where $M$ is an $A_1$-module and $N$ is an $A_2$-module.

What we have so far is using the fact that $(a_1,a_2) = (a_1,0) + (0,a_2)$.  We can get $(a_1,0)T = T_1$ and $(0,a_2)T = T_2$ are both submodules of $T$.  So $T = T_1 + T_2$.

We are having problems showing that $T_1 \cap T_2$ is trivial.  Once we have that fact then $T_1$ and $T_2$ are isomorphic to $M$ and $N$ respectively.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note you can define $T_1$ as the set of elements in $T$ fixed by $(1, 0) \in A_1 \times A_2$ and you can define $T_2$ as the set of elements fixed by $(0, 1)$.  If you're fixed by both $(1, 0)$ and $(0, 1)$ then you're fixed by their product.

Comment: You are assuming that $A_1$ and $A_2$ are unitary.  Which they aren't.

Comment: Ah, in that case, how do you know that $T = T_1 + T_2$?

Comment: In fact, how do you know that $T_1$ and $T_2$ are nonzero?  What if $M$ was a module with the zero action $a\cdot m = 0$?

Comment: Well if it was zero, then it would be isomorphic to $0 \oplus 0$.  Also I know that $T = T_1 + T_2$ as $(a_1,a_2)T = (a_1,0)T + (0,a_2)T$.

Comment: I'm not saying what if $T$ is zero, I'm saying what if the **action** is zero.  So what if $T$ is nonzero but for any $t \in T$ and any $a \in A$ we have $a\cdot t = 0$?  In non-unital rings it is not always true that every element $t \in T$ in the module can be written as $t = a\cdot t'$ for some $a \in A$ and $t' \in T$.